# What's an alternative to placeholder text in forms?

Tags: forms, input-fields, labels

I'm designing a form for elderly (65+) and I'm focussing on good readability and high contrast.

I want to let them know which format they have to use while typing their birthdate (e.g. dd-mm-yyyy), phonenumber etc. I can't use placeholder text because of it being less recognisable as an input field, bad contrast (when I use grey text) and a higher chance for errors.

I did some research and an option, although debatable, would be [floating text labels](http://bradfrost.com/blog/post/float-label-pattern/). The reason why I can't use this is because the font-size is too small and it wouldn't really solve the problem because otherwise I could just put the required format in the field label.

What is an alternative I can use?

Answer (score 2):

Display a help-text under the field and make use of a datepicker.

Or have a look at [Most User-Friendly Form Fields for Entering Date/Time?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1232/most-user-friendly-form-fields-for-entering-date-time)